# Compare variable against previous variable in a while loop PHP

Tags: php

I have a while loop where I want to compare the current variable ($high) to the previous one.  If the value is higher I want to show a green background and if it is lower I want to show a red background.

At the moment, if the value is higher, then it shows a red background, also it only seems to compare the latest result and not all of the values in the loop.

[Link to test page](http://job-app.co.uk/ecap/services/test.php)

```
$previous = 0;
while ($row =mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $high = $row['High'];
    if ($high > $previous){
        ?> <span style="background:green"><?php echo $row['High']; ?></span><?PHP
    }else{
        ?> <span style="background:red"><?php echo $row['High']; ?></span><? PHP
    }
    $previous = row;
}
```

Comment: 1.`mysql_*` is deprecated and removed library now, so upgrade yourself to PHP7 along with `mysqli_*` or `PDO`. 2. `$previous = row;` needs to be `$previous = $high;`

Comment: you are assigning the entire $row dataset to $previous, which will be an array, and that will be used to compare instead of the actual value of $row['High'];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysql_*` is deprecated and removed library now, so upgrade yourself to `PHP7` along with `mysqli_*` or `PDO` libraries.

`$previous = row;` needs to be `$previous = $high;`

Output:-https://eval.in/1058293

Answer (score 1):

At present the code stores the previous `$row`, not he specific `$row['High']`.  Please change

```
$previous = $row;
```

to

```
$previous = $row['High'];
```

Comment: Or even `$previous = $high;`